# List updating in python

Tags: python, list

I want to create a new list every time in the loop. So that the list has new values every time the loop runs. Please see the code.

```
pis=[]
ns=[]
ps=[]
for pk in arange(0,1,0.05):
    #print pk, ':'
    pis.append(pk)
    initialize()
    for t in xrange(10):
        #a=float(a)
        sumValue = sum(cmath.exp(g.node[i]['theta'] * cmath.sqrt(-1)) for i in g.nodes_iter())
        r = abs(sumValue/g.number_of_nodes())
        print r   
        #pis.append(t)
        ps.append(r)
        update()
    k=max(ps)
    ns.append(k)



plot(pis, ns)
```

I want to find the maximum value everytime the loop runs for pk, and store that value in ns[]. Next time the loop runs I do not want to have ns[] values from previous loops. Is there a way, please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Code you want to run on every iteration of a loop goes inside the loop. If you want to make a new list on every iteration, you should make a new list inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `ns=[]` inside the loop.

```
pis=[]
ps=[]
for pk in arange(0,1,0.05):
    ns=[]
...
```

This will make `ns` an empty list every time the loop starts.